# What is the fastest way to copy data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am having two tables, one is `Staging` and another one is `Report`. All processing happens in `Staging` and upon completion of such process I have to copy all the records to `Report`.

The `Staging` table contains millions of records so I just want to know what is the fastest way to copy this data to `Report`.

3 options which I know are:

- `Insert into`
- `Select into`
- creating a package and executing it via a job.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another option is BCP out (queryout) and then BCP  in/BULK INSERT

you can also use the BULK INSERT task in SSIS

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Transferring Data from One Table to Another](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3507171/Transferring-Data-from-One-Table-to-Another.htm)

It discusses

- The INSERT INTO Method
- The DTS Import/Export Wizard method
- The BCP/Bulk Insert Method